# When is $x^x=y^y$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I just stumbled about this question: [If $x^x=y^y$ and $x,y>1$, prove that $x=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474703/if-xx-yy-and-x-y1-prove-that-x-y)

All the proves mentioned there involve the fact that $x,y$>1. On $[0,1]$ this fucntion has a minimum at $\frac1e$ and is monotone on $[0,\frac1e]$ and monotone on $[\frac1e,1]$. So $\forall x\in[0,\frac1e]\exists y\in[\frac1e,1]$ with $x^x=y^y$.

Is there a "closed" function that maps $x\mapsto y$?

Comment: since x,y are positive, taking the log of both sides leads to x=y. To prove this start from x=y.

Comment: Take a look at the Lambert W function (sometimes known as the Lambert Omega function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x$ and $y$ reals and $0<x<1$ & $0<y<1$ ,

the solving of $y^y=x^x$ for $y$ leads to :
$$\begin{cases} y=e^{W_0\big(x\ln(x)\big)} \\
y=e^{W_{-1}\big(x\ln(x)\big)} \end{cases}
$$
where $W$ is the LambertW function, which is a multi-valuated function in this range. The two branches are referenced as $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ .

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

PROOF ( on the range $0<x<1$ & $0<y<1$) :

$x^x=y^y \quad\to\quad x\ln(x)=y\ln(y)=e^{\ln(y)}\ln(y)$
$$\ln(y)e^{\ln(y)}=x\ln(x)$$
$ze^z=t \quad\to\quad \begin{cases}z=W_0(t)\\z=W_{-1}(t)\end{cases}\quad$ on $-\frac{1}{e}<t<0$.

With $z=\ln(y)$ and $t=x\ln(x)\quad\to\quad \ln(y)=\begin{cases} W_0\big(x\ln(x)\big) \\
W_{-1}\big(x\ln(x)\big) \end{cases}$

$$y=\begin{cases} e^{W_0\big(x\ln(x)\big)} \\
e^{W_{-1}\big(x\ln(x)\big)} \end{cases}$$

Note :

$\qquad e^{W_{-1}\big(x\ln(x)\big)} =x\quad$  in $0<x<1/e$

$\qquad e^{W_0\big(x\ln(x)\big)} =x\quad$  in $1/e<x<1$

Thus, both corresond to the trivial solution $y=x$.

$$ $$
[image]